# Android.Widget.TextView

Tags: c#, android, widget, textview, monodevelop

I am trying to change the color of a `textview` in Android MonoDevelop.

I have tried this:

```
TextView mapTextView = new TextView(contextOverlay); 
mapTextView.Text = overlayDetailsForThisOverlay.stringName; 
mapTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

I get the following error:

> `Android.Widget.TextView` does not contain a definition for `setTextColor`.

I have tried to add the following as a using statement:

```
using `Android.Graphics`;
```

With no luck.

May I please have some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand if you want to change the background color or the text color. Anyway, to change the text color you should use this:

```
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
tv.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0));//ARGB 255 255 0 0 is red
```

And to change the background color:

```
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 255, 0));//ARGB 255 0 255 0 is green
```

Don't forget to put this in your imports:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of your textview you should use this:

```
tv.SetTextColor(Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.textcolor));
```

But first you must create an xml file(Color.xml) inside the Values folder containing this following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="textcolor">#ffcc33</color>
</resources>
```